# How to use multi query with nodejs express mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

How to use multi query like find , update , insert , delete in one service  on mongodb

I can query this below

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {

  User.find({},function (err, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
  });
});
```

but i want to query like this is an error

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
  var data = array();
  User.find({},function (err, docs) {
     data['data1'] = docs
  })
  Content.find({},function (err, docs) {
    data['data2']  = docs
  })
  res.json(docs)
});
```

Can anyone help me or It is possible to use query like this?
Thank you

Comment: in your response you pass res.json(docs) not valid because you push the data in data array. 

so pass the response res.json(data)

Answer (score 1):

You can use async await to run multiple mongo queries inside a function like below:

```
router.get('/userlist', async function(req, res) {
   var data = array();
   try{
       //first query
       let user_data = await User.find({}).exec();
       data['data1'] = user_data;

       //second query
       let content_data = await Content.find({}).exec();
       data['data2']  = content_data;

       return res.status(200).json(data)
   }
   catch(err){
       return res.status(400).json({err})
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My question is what is stopping you? Yes, you can do this. I did those kinds of works.

There remain two points.

If you need to perform multiple queries, based on the response of the previous query, you can use `async/await` or `promises`. If you don't wanna try those, there is still a way. You can check the response of the previous query, make conditions, and if right, execute the seconde one. And thus you can make a chain of queries.

And if you don't need to rely on the responses, do whatever you want. There is nothing wrong...

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for your database call response. So, You can use promise for this. [MDN: Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) Make promise of database call and resolve that after you got data from database. Promise.all will wait until your both the promises resolved. [MDN: Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
  var data = [];
  let promise1 =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    User.find({},function (err, docs) {
      data['data1'] = docs;
      resolve();
    })
  });

  let promise2 =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Content.find({},function (err, docs) {
      data['data2']  = docs
    })
  });

  Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(result => res.json(docs))
});
```

Comment: I send my response like this,
res.type('json');
res.jsonp(data);